# OpenLayers: display remote kml

Tags: networking, dynamic, openlayers, kml

I'm trying to let OpenLayers display a KML file that was retrieved from a server.
For some reason this does not work.
Similar questions have been asked, but I could not find a working example.
What I did was improve one of the examples in the OpenLayers distribution: kml-track.js

I improved it with what I found. This is what it looks like. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
Any pointers are welcome

---

```
var map ;

function init() {
  var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
  var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");

  //note that I have host equal to location//   //Math.Random will stop caching//
  var mykmlurl = 'http://myserver/kml-track.kml';

  map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    projection: mercator,
    layers: [
      new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),

      //Defiine your KML layer//
      new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("This Is My KML Layer", {
        //Set your projection and strategies//
        projection: geographic,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        //set the protocol with a url//
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
          //set the url to your variable//
          url: mykmlurl,
          //format this layer as KML//
          format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            //maxDepth is how deep it will follow network links//
            maxDepth: 1,
            //extract styles from the KML Layer//
            extractStyles: true,
            //extract attributes from the KML Layer//
            extractAttributes: true
          })
        }),
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
          "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
            graphicName: "circle",
            pointRadius: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            fillColor: "#ffcc66",
            strokeColor: "#666633",
            strokeWidth: 1
          })
        })
      })
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-93.2735, 44.8349).transform(geographic, mercator),
    zoom: 8
  });


 //function called// //timer// //layer to refresh//
  window.setInterval(UpdateKmlLayer, 5000, MyKmlLayer);
}

function UpdateKmlLayer(layer) {
  //setting loaded to false unloads the layer//
  layer.loaded = false;
  //setting visibility to true forces a reload of the layer//
  layer.setVisibility(true);
  //the refresh will force it to get the new KML data//
  layer.refresh({ force: true, params: { 'key': Math.random()} });
}
```

---

Comment: you say that it doesnt work. does it not display at all? if you check in a javascript debugging console is the KML file being requested?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how to display a KML layer in OpenLayers which might help you:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html

Are you getting any errors when opening your page - or does it run ok but nothing appear? If you're not getting any errors then it might indicate an issue with how your projections are set up (i.e. your features might not appear where you expect them to)